# pgbadger - how to get cancelled queries in text format?

Tags: postgresql, pgbadger

I want to create report on cancelled queries in postgresql.
When I generate a pgbadger report in text format, information about cancelled queries is not added, while they are present in html format.

Is it a missing feature of pgbadger?

Edit: the command I am running is

```
pgbadger -x text -j 8 -J 8 -m 25600 --outdir /home/0084 --remote-host postgres_server1 /var/log/pg/postgresql-${date}_*.log -f stderr
```

Comment: Can you show the code you've written to attempt what you're asking about?

Comment: I am running pgbadger as: pgbadger -x text -j 8 -J 8 -m 25600 --outdir /home/0084 --remote-host postgres_host1 /var/log/pg/postgresql-${date}_*.log -f stderr